# How to disable Network in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, security, networking, administration

I have a virtual machine on VMWare Workstation with Windows Server 2008 R2.
There are some **not** admin users. They have to have an internet access for theirs work (for example, to use SVN, Maven and so on). But at the same time, I have to close access to the Network for them.
What i have already tried:

1. I've tried to turn off **network discovery** in **Network and Sharing Center**. But it disables network only via gui(explorer), so users still can access other devices like that *\\SOME_MACHINE_PC*. More then that, users (which are even not admins) can change back this option in Control Panel.
2. I've tried to edit registry, adding such configuration:

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Network]
   "NoEntireNetwork "=dword:00000001
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
   "NoNetHood"=dword:00000001

But it have not changed anything at all.

3. I've tried to change **Network Adapter** config in WMware to **Host-only: A private network shared with the host.**
   But this turns off internet.

**So, is there any other variants?**

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extra subnet for the VM, and don't route from this subnet to the company network.Then you can access the VM via the Host System (I am doing it via vnc). When the VM doesn't need access to the host network, it should work.

If the VM needs access to the company lan:
You could create a second VM for the internet only use, and use the existing VM for its current purpose.